# How to use v-for variable from slot in the parent component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

How to solve this error when I try to use variable in `slot` from `v-for` in `Vue.js`?

> Property or method "slide" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property

This is how I use component:

```
<Slides v-model="slides">
  <AnotherComponent v-model="slide.someproperty" />
```

In `Slides` component I have `v-for`:

```
<div v-for="(slide, index) in value" :key="slide.id">
        <comp1 v-model="slide.prop1"></dropper>
        <slot></slot>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly what [scoped slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots) are for.

For example, in your `Slides` template

```html
<slot :slide="slide"></slot>
```

and in the parent...

```html
<Slides v-model="slides">
  <AnotherComponent slot-scope="{ slide }" v-model="slide.someproperty"/>
```

---

Note: If using Vue < 2.5, you can only use `slot-scope` on a `<template>` element.